# Is it possible to use three LISTAGGs and group by elements in row?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation, listagg

I have a situation where I would like to put three different columns, each which have multiple rows, into a single row.

I am using this code, which works to give me all of the first columns, then the second columns, then the third.

```
   , '(' ||(LISTAGG(billing_item_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by eduid) || ' | ' ||  LISTAGG(billing_item_amount, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by eduid))  || ' | ' ||  LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR(instance_name,'^[A-Z]{3,4} [0-9]{4}'), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (order by eduid) || ')' as billing
```

The results are:

```
321718277   Anon Person SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL  2022-2023   (606547, 606550 | 225, 225 | ENGL 1175, MATH 1153)
```

What I would like to see is

```
321718277   Anon Person SENIOR HIGH SCHOOL  2022-2023   (606547|225|ENGL 1175),(606550|225|MATH 1153)
```

The billing id, 606547, amount 225, and course ENGL 1175 are all on the same row.

Comment: I used the following code, but it didn't work:

, (LISTAGG(billing_item_id, ', ') || LISTAGG(billing_item_amount, ', ') || LISTAGG(instance_name, ', '))  WITHIN GROUP (order by eduid) as billing

Comment: can you just do 3 different listaggs, as subqueries, and then join all those 3 together.  WITH agg_item AS (select first list agg), agg_course AS (select another listagg) SELECT A.ID, A.listagg1, B.listagg2, C.listagg3 FROM agg_item INNER JOIN agg_course ON agg_item.id = agg_course.id ....   etc?  sorry didnt have time to give full attention and answer, but this is how I do it

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate value within `listagg`, not `listagg`s themselves. Something like this:

```
SQL> with test(eduid, billing_item_id, billing_item_amount, instance_name) as
  2    (select 1, 606547, 225, 'ENGL 1175' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 606550, 225, 'MATH 1153' from dual
  4    )
  5  select listagg('(' || billing_item_id     ||'|'||
  6                        billing_item_amount ||'|'||
  7                        REGEXP_SUBSTR(instance_name,'^[A-Z]{3,4} [0-9]{4}') || ')', ',')
  8         within group (order by eduid) as billing
  9  from test;

BILLING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(606547|225|ENGL 1175),(606550|225|MATH 1153)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot.  Yes. That was the syntax I needed.

```
 , listagg('(' || billing_item_id     ||'|'|| billing_item_amount ||'|'||  REGEXP_SUBSTR(instance_name,'^[A-Z]{3,4} [0-9]{4}') || ')', ',')  within group (order by eduid) as billing
```